# HttpHeaders ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, http-headers, google-api, classcastexception

I started tinkering with OAuth2 stuff in order to play with the new Google Tasks API.  I seem to get all that done successfully and receive my auth token.  But when I try to set up any of the HTTP request stuff I start running into trouble.

Here's the culprit; I'm currently receiving a `ClassCastException` on the following line:

```
HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
```

I've seen this exact line used in many examples from Google regarding use of their APIs.  Here is the full stack trace...

```
06-17 08:59:41.195: WARN/System.err(2765): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.api.client.http.HttpHeaders
06-17 08:59:41.242: WARN/System.err(2765):     at com.example.tasks.GoogleTasks.authenticatedClientLogin(GoogleTasks.java:142)
06-17 08:59:41.249: WARN/System.err(2765):     at com.example.tasks.GoogleTasks.access$1(GoogleTasks.java:138)
06-17 08:59:41.249: WARN/System.err(2765):     at com.example.tasks.GoogleTasks$2$1.run(GoogleTasks.java:108)
06-17 08:59:41.249: WARN/System.err(2765):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-17 08:59:41.249: WARN/System.err(2765):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-17 08:59:41.257: WARN/System.err(2765):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-17 08:59:41.257: WARN/System.err(2765):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
06-17 08:59:41.257: WARN/System.err(2765):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 08:59:41.257: WARN/System.err(2765):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-17 08:59:41.265: WARN/System.err(2765):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
06-17 08:59:41.265: WARN/System.err(2765):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
06-17 08:59:41.273: WARN/System.err(2765):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I was hoping someone could help me determine why this line isn't working for me, but seems to be fine in many other cases.

Comment: just check if you dont have some other imports, because HttpHeaders class is there in apache.http as well